# How can i make a curl request in laravel without leaving my current page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am in a Laravel view with an input field and a button, so I want to make a request to an external API.

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" name="licence" id="licence" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Validate BVN</button>
```

The CURL request just URL and the licence input field will be submitted.

```
curl "url" \
-X GET
```

The curl request returns some variables like first and last name.

Trying to use this ajax request from the laravel view.

I am trying a JavaScript request like this to a route, but I am not able to get it to work.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('#getRequest').click(function(){
            $.get('getRequest', function(data){
                console.log(data);
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

While the route is

```
Route::get('/home/getRequest', 'WalletController@ajaxreq');
```

How do I send the input field along with the request and return the values of the API from the controller back to the view?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a "write the code for me" service, show us what you have tried and why it didn't work with details of error if any

Comment: Use [`fetch()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: I have edited the question..sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

For the page doesn't reload, you must prevent the "submit" event the button, it is reloading your page (because your action form is probably empty and your method form is GET).

```
$('#getRequest').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    $.get('getRequest', function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
});
```